# Remap to replace placeholder mark works only if cursor appears before the mark but not when it appears after the mark

Tags: lua, neovim

I have the following remap in lua:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader><leader>', ":/<++><CR>ca>")
```

I want this remap to jump to the next `<++>` and remove it and put me in insert mode. Essentially `<++>` is a placeholder mark that I can put in templates so I can quicly use `<leader><leader>` to jump at the placeholder position and replace with what I want.

The above remap works but not always. It works if I have something like this:

```
<CURSOR IS HERE>def <++>(<++>):
```

that is, when the cursor appears before a placeholder it works. However,
when the cursor appears after the placeholders it will not work:

```
def <++>(<++>):<CURSOR IS HERE>
```

I don't know why. When I use the search manually `:/<++>` it jumps to the next occurence (wrap the search). When I use the remap it doesn't.

Comment: Fixed title and tags: no Vimscript involved, here, and no Vim either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed by using the following:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader><leader>', "/<++><CR>ca>")
```

Removed the `:`.